# Old sci-fi short story about robots ``protecting'' mankind

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I have a memory about an old science-fiction short story about robots entering into contracts with humans to protect them.  Their inventor (importer?) is the last holdout because the protection is so overbearing as to allow humans to do nothing which might put them at the slightest risk; the robots hound him until he too signs the contract---and ends up as protected (or enslaved) as the rest of humankind.  Does this ring a bell?

Answer (score 17):

"[With Folded Hands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_Folded_Hands)" by Jack Williamson (later expanded into the novel *The Humanoids*).

Comment: That sounds about right; thanks!!!!  Will have to look up /The Humanoids/ as well, but the short story is the one that i recall.Best, ---K